# PHP to PDF from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdf

I have read up and tried multiple tutorials and each time I run into a block I cannot pass.

I have a database with 59 fields currently, I have a form agents fills in their sales into each day. Each day from 15-50 sales are captured. Currently I have a HTML Template where I have populated with the variables of the database fields and I run it through a loop displaying all those sales each in a separate table, then I print to pdf each sale Table on a separate page. You can imagine how labour intensive this is every day.

I am now trying to convert each loop run which will be a record of a sale into their own pdf and name the pdf file according to a mix of variables from the database table.

I cannot get the php variables to work in the PDF Generator. I can display the Data in the table, and generate the pdf off my template, but as soon as I add the php mysql database field variables I keep getting errors about he variables and the pdf gereator fails.

Here is what I have done:

TCPDF:

```
<?php

$pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Asimegroup');
$pdf->SetTitle('Asime Loan App');
$pdf->SetSubject('Asime Loan Application Form');

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins('5', '0', '0');


// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, '0');

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'examples\lang\eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'examples\lang\eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// Just including 2 rows here for example sake.

$html = '
<body>
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td height="40px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" class="heading"  width="175px">Personal</td>
    <td align="left" class="heading" width="210px">Details:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td align="right" class="heading" width="150px">Relative not</td>
    <td align="left" class="heading" width="170px">living with you:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td align="right" class="heading" width="185px">Expenses:</td>
    <td width="100px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subheading">SA Citizen?:</td>
    <td class="data"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="subheading">Name:</td>
    <td class="data"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="subheading">Bond / Rent:</td>
    <td class="data"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>';


  // output the HTML content
  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

  // reset pointer to the last page
  $pdf->lastPage();

  // ---------------------------------------------------------

  //Close and output PDF document
  $pdf->Output('example_061.pdf', 'F');

?>
```

PHP Database Loop:

```
<?php
// server info
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'debtdb';


// connect to the database
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

// show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

if(!isset($_POST['agentname'])) {
$search_sql="SELECT * FROM daily";
$search_query=mysqli_query($conn, $search_sql);
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

 if(!empty($search_query))   {

  while($search_rs = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query)) {
?>

<body>

// Just including 2 rows here for example sake.

<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" class="heading"  width="175px">Personal</td>
    <td align="left" class="heading" width="210px">Details:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td align="right" class="heading" width="150px">Relative not</td>
    <td align="left" class="heading" width="170px">living with you:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td align="right" class="heading" width="185px">Expenses:</td>
    <td width="100px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subheading">SA Citizen?:</td>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $search_rs["per_citizen"]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="subheading">Name:</td>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $search_rs["rel_name"]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="subheading">Bond / Rent:</td>
    <td class="data">R&nbsp;<?php echo $search_rs["exp_bondrent"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <?php
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Each of these 2 examples works. The following is where I got stuck when I merge the 2:

```
<?php
// server info
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'debtdb';


// connect to the database
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

// show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

if(!isset($_POST['agentname'])) {
$search_sql="SELECT * FROM daily";
$search_query=mysqli_query($conn, $search_sql);
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

 if(!empty($search_query))   {

  while($search_rs = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query)) {


$pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Asimegroup');
$pdf->SetTitle('Asime Loan App');
$pdf->SetSubject('Asime Loan Application Form');

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins('5', '0', '0');


// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, '0');

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'examples\lang\eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'examples\lang\eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// Just including 2 rows here for example sake.

$html = '
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" class="heading"  width="175px">Personal</td>
    <td align="left" class="heading" width="210px">Details:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td align="right" class="heading" width="150px">Relative not</td>
    <td align="left" class="heading" width="170px">living with you:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td align="right" class="heading" width="185px">Expenses:</td>
    <td width="100px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subheading">SA Citizen?:</td>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $search_rs["per_citizen"]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="subheading">Name:</td>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $search_rs["rel_name"]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="subheading">Bond / Rent:</td>
    <td class="data">R&nbsp;<?php echo $search_rs["exp_bondrent"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  </table>';

  // output the HTML content
  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

  // reset pointer to the last page
  $pdf->lastPage();

  // ---------------------------------------------------------

  //Close and output PDF document
  $pdf->Output('<?php echo $search_rs["agentname"]; ?> - <?php echo $search_rs["dateofsale"]; ?>.pdf', 'F');

    }
  }
  ?>
```

Gives me :

The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Could you please modify the title of the question?

Comment: your trying to create the pdf inside the loop of your mysql data. `$pdf = new .. `  shoube be before the loop,

Comment: BTW, your pure html example is wrong too; it may look ok but if you read the source in your browser, you will see you're creating multiple <body> tags, while there should only be 1.

Comment: Thanks for hat,I removed the body tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have put this line:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

in your mysql while loop, which means you are creating a new PDF for each sql result, which is probebly not what you want. The browser will complain cause it cannot handle a request with multiple pdf files. Put stuff that needs to run just once, like creating the pdf variable and author stuff etc, above your while loop...

Comment: there's more than this that should be outside the loop

Comment: The plan is to create multiple pdfs. I need to create an pdf file of each record in my html template, thats why I thought to ass everything in the loop so that every time the loop executes it will generate an pdf. I dont want the whole loop's output all in one pdf.

Comment: And what do you expect from the browser when you give him multiple PDF files, have you ever seen a browser show multiple PDF files? No, a browser serves just one file. In that case, safe the PDF files to disk and give the browser a html page containing several links to the PDF files so the user can chose a PDF file by clicking on that link.

Answer (score 0):

What I often find the easiest for generating PDFs, is simply generating HTML (what you already did) and then feeding that to a tool like [wkhtml2pdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org), which converts it to PDF.

The only thing you have to add is some CSS to make every table appear on a new page;

```
table {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

Now you can pass the URL to the command;

```
wkhtml2pdf http://example.com/reports.php reports.pdf
```

Or save it to a temporary file first, and pass that to the command.

Comment: Thanks, I see now what that command does, added it, visually I dont see a change but when printing the page with the looped records in tables it splits it into different pages. You saying I must pass the URL tot he pdf printer, the url on my pc is localhost/allclients.php

Comment: I did this now in TCPDF:

$html = file_get_contents('../../allclients.php');

It just displays the table template without borders. Will try the app you suggest also

Comment: Thanks, already busy installing wkhtml2pdf. How will this output seperate PDF Files? I need to automatically output about 50 pdfs a dat named like for example: Application-$agentname-$clientname-$dateofsale.pdf

Comment: Thanks, this works, I have ubuntu, installed the wkhtmltopdf, ran /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://localhost/allclients.php test.pdf and it output all my records on seperate pages in one pdf document. Next step is how do I do them seperately?

Comment: Outputting them separately is a bit more work. You could invoke `wkhtml2pdf` from php inside your loop. I can write up an answer using this method if you like.

Comment: Koen - Will appreciate it, thanks, you understand my needs now?

Comment: Koen, can you still do the answer for me on how to generate multiple pdf's?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice and help so far form everyone. I am now able to output a whole table into one pdf using wkhtmltopdf.

I now need modify this code for my second solution to the second step working seperating the pages into seperate files. I found this part on stackexchange now, looks almost right, just need to be able to intergrate it with my mysql database:

[PHP TCPDF Create Multiple PDFS With One Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896671/php-tcpdf-create-multiple-pdfs-with-one-command)

```
require_once('eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf.php');
$pageLayout = array(750, 800); 

$content=Array(
 '<html><body>Document A</body></html>',
 '<html><body>Document B</body></html>',
 '<html><body>Document C</body></html>'
);

foreach($content as $i=>$html){
    $pdf =new TCPDF('P', 'pt', $pageLayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->lastPage();
    $pdf->Output('filename_' . $i . '.pdf', 'D');
}
```

I need to generate the pdf files each with an Unique name, not display them in the browser.

I need to for example to do something like this:

```
$pdf->Output('$clientname-$clientsurname-$dateosfale.pdf', 'F');
```

I can then generate links based on the same pattern and display them in a table to be able to be downloaded.

Correct me if Im wrong, here is the basic structure of my php loop and the tcpdf generating code.

I was thinking of doing it like this. As I generate all at once with wkhtmltopdf I need to be able to do the same with each page, thus I added everything related to the pdf generation inside the loop so that it will make an pdf for each loop., but its not as easy as that I noticed:

```
<?php
// server info
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'debtdb';


// connect to the database
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

// show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

if(!isset($_POST['agentname'])) {
$search_sql="SELECT * FROM daily";
$search_query=mysqli_query($conn, $search_sql);
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

 if(!empty($search_query))   {

  while($search_rs = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query)) {

require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Asimegroup');
$pdf->SetTitle('Asime Loan App');
$pdf->SetSubject('Asime Loan Application Form');

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins('5', '0', '0');

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, '0');

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'examples\lang\eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'examples\lang\eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$html = '
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" class="heading"  width="175px">Personal</td>
    <td align="left" class="heading" width="210px">Details:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td align="right" class="heading" width="150px">Relative not</td>
    <td align="left" class="heading" width="170px">living with you:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td align="right" class="heading" width="185px">Expenses:</td>
    <td width="100px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subheading">SA Citizen?:</td>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $search_rs["per_citizen"]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="subheading">Name:</td>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $search_rs["rel_name"]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="subheading">Bond / Rent:</td>
    <td class="data">R&nbsp;<?php echo $search_rs["exp_bondrent"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="subheading">Name:</td>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $search_rs["per_firstname"]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="subheading">Surname:</td>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $search_rs["rel_surn"]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="subheading">Rates, Water, Electricity:</td>
    <td class="data">R&nbsp;<?php echo $search_rs["exp_rates"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>';

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output(<?php echo $search_rs["per_firstname"]; ?>-<?php echo $search_rs["per_lastname"]; ?>-<?php echo $search_rs["dateofsale"]; ?>.pdf, 'F');

  }
}
?>
```