# Creating multiple PDFs with TCPDF in a while loop

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to create hundreds of PDF files with TCPDF using a while loop. The problem is that it seems to create only the first one and then stops. I turned on error reporting and there is no error.

I basically get the data with:

```
ob_start();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) { 

   $invoice_id = $row['invoice_id'];

   require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

   // create new PDF document
   $pdf = new MYCUSTOMPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
   
   // All $pdf-> settings are here

   // add a page
   $pdf->AddPage();
   $pdf->lastPage();
   $pdf->Output('/path/to/'.$invoice_id.'.pdf', 'F');
   echo "Generated ". $invoice_id."\n";

}
```

The .PDF gets generated fine, but it stops there. It doesn't continue with the next in the loop.

Anybody with TCPDF experience knows what is wrong? I can't figure it out and there is no error even with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896671/php-tcpdf-create-multiple-pdfs-with-one-command

Comment: wondering why your require_once is inside the loop. if it "has to be in the loop" because it does stuff, then require_once is the wrong require, because it will only be run once. (also, maybe it changes `$data`?) ;o) finally: are you certain that there's actually more than one row?

Comment: I dug into this myself and found that there is two issues with this. No answer, but wish there was. 
1. When you use $pdf->Output(); it forces close(), which then cancels you to recreate another PDF.
2. The only work around that I've was unable to test, was to create a function that call during the loop. sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/73dd3a84 all other options on stackoverflow did not work for me. There are older links that implies you can create a zipfile and then stuff all the pdfs into that, but I could not get that to work either. Good luck  mate.